# CKE: How to add css to my plugin?

Tags: css, plugins, ckeditor

I've made plugin by this tutorial.

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Tutorials/Timestamp_Plugin

It adds this code into the cursor position:

```
<div class="cut" contenteditable="false" ><!-- CUT --></div>
```

Woundering how to add css for it.
Now I've added my own css for this into contents.css, but I'm sure there is a way to connect css from plygin's folder.
How do I?

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at this:

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.stylesSet

I think the addExternal will do the job for you.